# Javascript Email Validation Specific Domain with PHP data

Tags: javascript, php

There is something wrong in this line:

```
var reg = /^[a-z.]+'@'+javaScriptVar$/;
```

but I don't know how to correctly write this. The current code would make "Please enter Email Address" appear every time. Here are the codes:

```
<?
$em=$_POST['myemail'];
$ar=split("@",$em);
?>

function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("User Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value.length == 0) {
        alert("Please enter Email Address");    
        return false;
    } else {
        var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $ar[1]; ?>";
        var reg = /^[a-z.]+'@'+javaScriptVar$/;  
        if (!reg.test(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value)) {
            alert("Please Enter Correct Email Domain"); 
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post interpreted value for javascriptVar (what you see in your browser rather than code)?

Comment: Writing a regular expression in the form `/…/` is kind of a special syntax (note that there are no quotes, so it is not a normal string literal), so I think you can not use normal string concatenation in there. I rather think you will have to use the `new RegExp(…)` syntax to create your regular expression dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to include an `@` in your regex to check for url validation. Since there are no quotes used around your regex, specifying it like `+'@'+` will not work.

Change it to:

`/^[a-z.]@javaScriptVar$/`

**EDIT:**

I think you are using the wrong regex to validate the `url`. Try this:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z0-9]+.{1}[a-z]{3}$/`

Comment: Are you getting some error while executing? Can you post an example?

Comment: I get "Please Enter Correct Email Domain" even if I entry the correct domain

Comment: I just tried var javaScriptVar = "test.com"; to see if it is my php problem, but I still get the same alert, so I think it should be still the /^[a-z.]@javaScriptVar$/ issue. Thanks.

Comment: var javaScriptVar = "test@test.com"; then I try abc@test.com, it would show alert "Please Enter Correct Email Domain").

Comment: How is `test@test.com` correct and `abc@test.com` wrong?

Comment: the program decides both are wrong. I cannot find a way to make this becomes a success case.

Comment: How is one different from the other?

Comment: I mean the result suppose to be let me add the record if the email domain is test.com, however in my testing with /^[a-z.]@javaScriptVar$/, the result is always "Please Enter Correct Email Domain" no matter I try an email with domain test.com or email with domain other than test.com. So I think /^[a-z.]@javaScriptVar$/ is not working.

Comment: Because `javaScriptVar` is part of the regex. Is `javaScriptVar` a variable?

Comment: as you can see above in the coding, var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $ar[1]; ?>";

Comment: Change your regex as follows: `'^[a-z.]@'+javaScriptVar+'$';`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but doesn't work. I think the question is about how to correctly put var in regex. I tried to use string instead of var, that worked.